# Import multiple big json files into a DataFrame with R

Tags: r

I have ~45 files of 5-6 Mo containing over 3000 json objects that I want to work with in R. I've been able to import each jsonr file independantly with fromJSON() as a list except one for which I had to use stream_in(), but am having trouble coercing it into a useful structure. I want to create a data frame merging with rbind all the files. The goal is to merge the result with the other file using cbind.

```
allfiles <- list.files()

for (file in allfiles) {
  jsonFusion <- fromJSON(file)

  file 1 <- do.call(rbind,jsonFusion)

}

stream_in(file("files2"))
```

The first step (loop) is a little bit slow and I don't know how to merge file 1 and file 2 and more how to have a dataframe!!!!

the function as.data.frame() is not working

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data structures are consistent.

```
library(jsonlite)  
all_files <- list.files(path = "path/to/files", full.names = TRUE)
rbind.pages(lapply(all_files,fromJSON))
```

Comment: Thanks Carl it's compiling faster but the result is still a list even if i do

Comment: dataset <- rbind.pages(lapply(all_files,fromJSON)); data <- as.data.frame(dataset)

Comment: you don't need the ";data<-as.data.frame(dataset)" part at all

Comment: Sorry carl! it's okay for the first problem! the second one is coming from another jsonfile where fromJSON("zizi.jsonr")
Error in feed_push_parser(readBin(con, raw(), n), reset = TRUE) : 
  parse error: trailing garbage
          di": "2.3", "wspdm": "3.7"}} {"status": "ok", "data": {"heat
                     (right here) ------^

Comment: Is that the one you are streaming in?

Comment: yes absolutely actually I found a solution but i don't understand why it works! fromJSON(sprintf("[%s]", paste(readLines("zizi.jsonr"), collapse=",")))

Comment: Meaning you're foggy on the step the function is taking? That's an awesome workaround by the way! Maybe this will help. https://github.com/Rterial/rticon/blob/master/examples/stack_example.md